# svg not rendering properly using `\includesvg`

Tags: graphics, luatex, svg

I am using Overleaf with LuaLaTex as my compiler. I have an svg which renders properly in a browser and looks like this:

[image: this is an example of working svg]

However, when using the command `\includesvg[width=\colwidth]{image.svg}`, the svg does not render properly and produces the following:

[image: this is an example of it not rendering properly]

Is this something to do with the compiler perhaps? With overleaf? I would prefer not to convert the svg to a png or pdf in order to maintain the best possible resolution.

Comment: Looks like a font issue: LaTeX thinks the font for (sans-serif) black-circled numbers ➊ ➋ ➌ ➍ ➎ ➏ ➐ ➑ ➒ ➓ is missing. Could you provide that svg file or its simplified version, perhaps through an overleaf sharing link?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ https://www.overleaf.com/read/nxypyvtfwgsy#57bccb the file is in figures/poster-cluster-matrix.svg

Comment: Why do you think printing or exporting the svg as pdf and including via package graphicx results in low resolution?

Comment: Bad news. From content of that svg, the black-circled numbers are consist of characters with Private Use Area codepoint from Wingdings font and filled white circle. For example `<path d="..." fill="#FFFFFF" fill-rule="evenodd"/><text font-family="Wingdings,Wingdings_MSFontService,sans-serif" font-weight="400" font-size="138" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1334.64 814)"></text>` uses character `` [U+F08D](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+F08D). Problem solved if it's possible to convert it to vector graphics in PDF. For this specific simple svg, maybe redraw it with Inkscape or even `tikz`?

Comment: If you don't want LaTeX to process the text within the SVG file, run the Inkscape export without additional "LaTeX magic" via
`\includesvg[width=\colwidth,inkscapelatex=false]{image.svg}`

Comment: Or if you want some text to be processed with LaTeX but not the circled numbers, convert the latter to paths in the svg.

Comment: @MS-SPO I don't know, but even if I wanted to, I couldn't. The svg I am dealing with was created in MS PPT and evidently neither Wingdings nor "tables" are not recognized by any svg to pdf conversion tool so I just get garbage out each time.

Comment: Thank you. So IF it renders ok in a browser, AND you have a pdf printer installed ... just print it to pdf. Next check `\includegraphics` from package `graphicx`. // If that fails, either revert to MS PPT if possible, or redo it in Tikz (it's not too difficult). // IF you can edit the svg beforehand to remove all those circled digits: remove them, save/print/export as pdf, have a look at package `tikz-imagelabels` (example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579177/245790)

Comment: Duh, oops forgot that I could print as pdf in Chrome. That worked (still have to jump through some hoops). Thank you! @MS-SPO